# UITableView with Core Data ordered by time, not alphabetically

Tags: uitableview, core-data, time

I'm working on an app that uses Core Data and a UITableView. What I've noticed is that when I add a new TableView entry, the cells seem to order alphabetically. Is there a way to make it so the cells are ordered by the time I add them (from top to bottom) rather than by the alphabet. Thanks!

Comment: This leaves a lot for us to guess in terms of your platform. You should tag/title your question with terms relevant to the libraries/language with which you are working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a timestamp field for your core data entity (type NSDate).  Then, you can use a simple sort descriptor on your fetch request to sort the entities as appropriate.

For example, after you create the entity...

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
[myNewEntity setValue:now forKey:@"timestamp"];
```

and then, in your fetch request...

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"MyEntity"];
NSSortDescriptor *sortByTimestamp = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"timestamp" ascending:YES];
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortByTimestamp];
```